# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected (timestamp, decode)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting this error `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`. If I remove the second line in my code I don't get the error, so I'm wondering if the issue has something to do with the DECODE or datatype of the TIME_P variable, which is timestamp.

```
TRUNC(TIME_P) >= TO_DATE('2009-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
TIME_P <= DECODE('2010-01-01', NOW, SYSDATE, TO_DATE('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  For instance, what is `NOW`?

Comment: NOW should return current date

Comment: . . What is the purpose of the `decode()`?  And `sysdate` is the current date as well.

Comment: In the code you have presented you are missing a single quote after the first date '2009-01-01 ... but I do not believe the error you are getting is because of that... As you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6b6a1851f1a7998520d2548bc540943a if now is just a column then your query is ok. So... like Gordon asked, what is NOW ?

Comment: "NOW should return current date " do you use MySQL or Oracle ? I am assuming you are using Oracle because ORA error but NOW is not a function in Oracle...

Comment: I use both, but for this it's Oracle

Comment: OK @M.Phys so did you thought that NOW will get you current time ? Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76f6bb721f4d757850172e4fdca3322c

Comment: can you just explain the logic of the second line? -- what do you want to achieve? `SYSDATE` is equivalent to `NOW`

Comment: DECODE('*', NOW, SYSDATE, TO_DATE('YYYY-MM-DD')). First arg is optional param, but it has to have a default value, which i specified as NOW. If left as NOW return SYSDATE

Comment: `TO_DATE('YYYY-MM-DD')` -- What is expected out of this? Still logic is unclear.

Comment: TIME_P is datatype timestamp, so it needs to be converted

Comment: The users sees 'NOW' as a default parameter. If they leave it as the default NOW, the SQL query should take the SYSDATE. Else if they specify a date, convert the timestamp of that column to a date

Comment: So now is a variable with a value in it ?

Comment: I misunderstood. 'NOW' is just a string. 'NOW' is the default value of the param. If the param is left as the default string 'NOW' return SYSDATE, otherwise return the date the user specified.

Comment: OK @M.Phys please check my answer. Comment on my answer if something is not ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are asking for  I believe:

```
DECODE(YOUR_FIRST_PARAMETER_HER, '2010-01-01', SYSDATE, TO_DATE(TRUNC(TIME_P), 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
```

AS you have mentioned "First arg is optional param" so I have entered the "YOUR_FIRST_PARAMETER_HER" expresion just to note to you that you will put it there.

Your error was occurring because of the format you have entered `('YYYY-MM-DD')` because the correct format is `'DD-MON-YYYY'` Also, before converting you will need to trunc that timestamp value...

Here you can see the errors that will occur if you do not use the right format and if you do not use trunc: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83cca74815a323bc72283adeb7396617

Answer (score 1):

Could I suggest something like this instead?

```
TIME_P >= DATE '2009-01-01' AND
TIME_P < (CASE WHEN NOW = '2010-01-01' THEN DATE '2010-01-01' ELSE SYSDATE END)
```

This uses date literals, `case` instead of `decode()` (`case` is standard SQL).  The initial `trunc()` is redundant, as well.

The second line doesn't really make sense to me.  If you just want dates that are not in the future, then:

```
TIME_P >= DATE '2009-01-01' AND
TIME_P < sysdate
```

Or if you want to pass in a parameter and use that instead of sysdate:

```
TIME_P >= DATE '2009-01-01' AND
TIME_P < COALESCE(:parameter, sysdate)
```